# Personalized URLs

Tags: php, mysql, apache

How someone implement personalized URLs in a website?

For example http://www.facebook.com/john

or
For example http://www.facebook.com/john.smith

Having in mind that the users choose their names (which will be unique and can not change once chosen).

Platform is Apache, PHP, Mysql

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_rewrite to redirect traffic to a different path which handles the routing.

If you look at many of the popular PHP frameworks they suggest using a provided .htaccess file which forwards all requests to index.php and from their include their own routing class/script

As part of the routing, you could check if the path matches an existing user, and then make the request display that users page.

Comment: How do I treat other non user pages like index3, indexmain, indexview etc?

Comment: Typically the routing will go through a list of rules and the first one that matches it uses. So other pages would be higher up in the list and match first.

Comment: Pls do u have a sample script i could try? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite all incoming requests to something like `http://example.com/index.php?q={request}`. Then you can grab `$_GET['q']` in PHP and do whatever you want with it. If it looks like a username, display the user's profile page, if it looks like the name of another page, include that page.

Comment: Thanks. Pls do u have a sample script I can try?

Comment: @Frank: http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/clean-urls-for-a-better-search-engine-ranking Google has tons of tutorials for mod_rewrite...